# How to add up player results across multiple games?

Tags: google-sheets

I have been using Google Sheets to track baseball player results from individual games. I have created separate sheets for each game. In each sheet I have the player name in column 1, their hits in column 2 and RBIs in column 3.

How can I create a master sheet to tabulate the statistics for each player from all of the different sheets (games played)?

I know I can just do:

```
 SUM('Game 1'!B1,'Game 2'!B1)
```

etc. for each player and stat in the master sheet, but this is tedious and doesn't scale well as I have to keep updating each formula for each player and stat every time I add a new game sheet.

Is there a way to add up all the hits, for example, for each player across all sheets with a simple formula that will recognize new sheets without having to explicitly add them to the formula as new games are added?

Or is there a better way of going about this?

I know how to do this with SQL databases but I don't have the time to build one for this project and was hoping to just be able to do it with a simple spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Without the specific sheets, I can only offer you a premise and a resource, although your example of the SUM() function tells me your on the right track.

First, to accomplish the dynamic tabs, you'll need to rely on the Indirect() function and a "helper" column to *point* to the sheet.  Indirect() uses a literal as an argument to return its reference. A literal can itself be a cell reference, that is a cell contains a value which is itself a reference to another cell (or in your case, tab).

I'll presuppose that your master sheet has (could have?) player names in column A, and the game states in each of the subsequent columns (B,C,D, ...) If the games tabs are labeled: Game1, Game2, Game3,..., then the Column B "header" would contain "Game1", Column C would be "Game2", Column D would be "Game3", ... (matching the tabs of the same names). The *tab names* in ROW 1, Col B, C, D, ... are used by the indirect() function to *help* point to the correct tab. This only gets you to the proper tab, though.

The second part utilizes the SUMIF(r,c,s) function which returns the SUM of all values S, where C (Criteria, lookup value) is TRUE/found in R (lookup range).  Here the we use the INDIRECT() function to patch together the sheets & ranges:

```
   --------- r---------- -c-  ------- s --------
```

=SUMIF(INDIRECT(B$1&"!A2:A"),$A2,INDIRECT(B$1&"!B2:B))

Broken down, this function call says (for the first part of the sumif()) get the game name in cell B$1 and to this name append our lookup criteria range IN THAT SHEET "!a2:a".  Notice the "!" -- this is the tab reference separator.  Given the above, this indirect function returns "Game1!a2:a" to the 1st (range lookup) parameter of the SUMIF().  The next part is NOT quoted in the formula '$A2'. it is the value being passed to the range lookup, which should be the first player in the list (col A). and finally, similarly the first part, this last part evaluates to the "Hits" range to be totaled "Game1!B2:B"

this...
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(B$1&"!A2:A"),$A2,INDIRECT(B$1&"!B2:B))

Entered in B2 (next to "Joe Smith" in A2) will then evaluate to and where B1 is 'Game1"

will evaluate to this...
=SUMIF(Game1!A2:A,A2,Game1!B2:B)

Note the use of absolute references in the functions. Copied down, the $A2 changes for each player listed, while copied across B$2 changes for each game.

reference:  https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/dynamic-sheet-tab-names-in-formulas/

Hope that helps.